# input как отправить или снять фокус без form

Tags: javascript, html, form, input

Сайт запаковывается Cordova и становится приложением для Android.
Есть несколько input, форма в моем случае не подходит, все они без неё. Ибо у меня input 80шт, каждый в форму оборачивать? Можно и так, но придется с CSS поиграться, ибо мне не подходит отступы и перенос строки у формы. Все input у меня расставлены.
Так вот, если input находится в form - то в телефоне при вводе значения, по клику Вперед/Enter/Перейти страница обновляется и экранная клавиатура скрывается.
Если же просто input - то Вперед/Enter/Перейти, не работает.

Мне нужно только чтобы по клику Вперед/Enter/Перейти у input снимался фокус и клавиатура все таки скрылась, отправка с перезагрузкой страницы не очень то нужна. 
Как решить ума ни приложу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Понял одно, нужно JS скрипт, который по нажатию Enter снимал бы фокус с текущего элемента и не перекидывал на следующий, просто снял и всё. Интернет перерыл есть подобное, но сам слепить не смог. Если обернуть в форму и на компе и в телефоне работает, но это как бы отправка формы, не то немного. Мне просто нужно снимать фокус с полей. Отправлять ненужно, соответственно и форму не желательно использовать.

Comment: лови событие отправки формы и отменяй.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю. Можешь поподробней? То есть мне нужно каждый мой input оборачивать формой? И того 80 форм. А если все таки формы, то скажем id и js для этого id и в нем вся суть?

Comment: можно в одну form положить

Comment: Видишь фишка какая, я пробовал в одну форму. В таком случае появляется кнопка Далее, по нажатию переходит в след. input и только на последнем input Перейти, ну и перезагрузка страницы срабатывает.

Comment: можно сделать запрет отправки формы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию фокус не переходит к следующему элементу по нажатию Enter. Можно отлавливать нажатие `Enter` и выполнять снимать фокус с `input`.
Форма отправляется по нажатию `Enter` только если есть в форме есть поле ввода с типом `submit`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach(
  function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        this.blur();
      }
    })
  });
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Я встречал, такое не на jQuery. Вот это бы мне подошло. Лишний вес программы, а так же в вашем примере вовсе нужен интернет.

Comment: @АнтонИванов про интернет несправедливое замечание, так как ничего не мешает подключить локальный файл.

Comment: Ну это опять же вес.
Я вот набросал
window.addEventListener ("keypress", function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;

 
        });

Вот только нужно снять чем то фокус. atert подставлял Enter отлавливает. Но немного не то похоже, лучше когда конкретно на input скрипт направлен querySelector например

Comment: @АнтонИванов убрал jQuery.

Comment: как только я собирался сообщить о том, что работает только первый input, как вы исправились. 
Большое вам спасибо.

Comment: Рано радаюсь https://yadi.sk/d/XUtH_obl3TGVpc вот скрин. А так же почему то работает только в https://jsfiddle.net/qyo491b0/3/  
В браузере же не работает, полагаю, что не на Денвере запущено.

Comment: @АнтонИванов убрал стрелочную функцию.

Comment: Alex78191, большое спасибо. Все сделал, в браузере не работало потому что скрипт находился выше самих input, переместил в файл js все работает, запаковал в apk, установил на телефон все работает. Выражаю благодарность.

Comment: @АнтонИванов скрипты лучше вызывать по событию `window.onload`. Стрелочную функцию можно было и не убирать?

Comment: Dreamweaver умная программа и не приемлет этого. Может быть быть и ничего страшного, не могу сказать точно.
А про window.onload не знаю и так работает.

Comment: @АнтонИванов Какая у вас версия Dreamweaver? Событие `window.onload` нужно для выполнения кода после загрузки DOM.

Comment: Dw CS6 год уже не знаю. год 2013 где то